# What is the area of physics/science called that deals with fundamental limits of computation?

Tags: quantum-information, terminology, information, landauers-principle

I am interested in learning about the fundamental limits of computation and in particular would like to read textbooks on the subject if they exist. My background is in maths and computer science - I am certainly not looking for books on complexity theory.

Example questions I am looking to answer/be able to interpret:

1. What is the amount of energy required (as a fundamental limit) to divide two numbers?
2. What is the smallest volume of space which can retrievably store $n$ bits of data?
3. What is the fundamentally shortest running time of an algorithm with $n$ steps? (where steps are suitably defined by some fundamental *physical* definition of a computer)

I have heard of quantum-information theory, but I'm not sure that's precisely what I'm looking for.

Comment: Computational complexity.

Comment: I don't see these questions well-formulated to have a single answer. For example, for question 1 you can have several devices from abacus to digital computers passing by analogic computers.

Comment: My question explicitly states I'm not looking for books on complexity theory, I am interested in fundamental physical limits.

As for varying devices, that is why the question is about fundamental limits.

Comment: Something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound)?

Comment: Computational complexity and Complexity theory are not the same.

Comment: Bekenstein bound seems highly relevant, thank you for the link. I will start digging there.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the name of a field, [Bremermann's limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremermann%27s_limit) is an example of the type of thing I'm looking for. This is the number of calculations of bits per second per kilogram of mass in a computer and is a fundamental limit derived from the laws of physics rather than an abstract computational model. Similarly the [Bekenstein bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound) is the amount of information you can store in a finite region of space with finite entropy. Thank you Jahan Claes for the link. I will follow links until I find a good text book.